# Detect if my controller is presented as popover

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uipopovercontroller

Using Xcode 10.1 and Swift 4.2.1, iOS 12

I got a tableview embedded in a navigation controller. In the upper right corner a bar button and a segue (popover) from this button to a navigation controller which holds a static table view, here the cells has further segues to other table views.

On an iPhone the static table view is displayed as a full screen modal, on an iPad it's a popover, which is okay so far.
I've set everything up in the storyboard, don't know if this could be the reason, but now I'm struggling to check if the view is a popover or a full screen modal.

I've tried:

```
print("\(presentationController)")
if presentationController is UIPopoverPresentationController {
    // Do something
}
```

But this doesn't work -> `print("\(presentationController)")` gives me `Optional(<_UIFullscreenPresentationController: 0x7fd00ad45770>)` on iPhone and iPad.

I've tried also with:

```
if popoverPresentationController != nil {
    print("popover")
}
```

But popover is printed if launched on iPhone or iPad.

Am I doing something wrong here or am I missing something?

Comment: @RajSharma I've read that one already. The initial question was written over 3 1/2 years ago, iOS8. The officially marked answer is just a small description without any code, which I tried by the way but wasn't able to come along with. Also other answers I've found are even older and in objective c (never used/written objective c before). So I would guess in iOS 12 are "some" changes and updates compared to iOS8, which maybe makes it easier to check if in a popover.

Answer (score 2):

Currently I'm using this:

```
if (popoverPresentationController?.arrowDirection != UIPopoverArrowDirection.unknown) {
    tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
    tableView.sectionFooterHeight = CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
}
```

It's easy, and it works. In case someone has a real possibility to find out "if is a popover", you are very welcome to post it in here.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I setup a view controller to be in a navigation controller. I then set the `modalPresentationStyle` to `.popover` on the navigation controller. On an iPhone it is presented full screen and on an iPad it is presented in a popover (let's ignore the app running as horizontally compact on the iPad).

In the view controller's `viewWillAppear` I wanted to adjust the view layout based on whether the view controller will actually be in a popover or be displayed full screen.

Even when being displayed full screen on an iPhone, all of the following properties give `.popover` (note that `self.parent` and `self.navigationController` are the same controller):

```
self.parent?.modalPresentationStyle
self.parent?.presentationController?.presentationStyle
self.popoverPresentationController?.presentationStyle
self.parent?.popoverPresentationController?.presentationStyle
```

Note that `self.parent?.presentationController`, `self.popoverPresentationController`, and `self.parent?.popoverPresentationController` all point to the same instance of a `UIPopoverPresentationController`.

The value for `self.modalPresentationStyle` and `self.presentationController?.presentationStyle` need to be ignored because `modalPresentationStyle` was not set at all on the view controller, just the navigation controller, so it defaults to `.pageSheet`.

The solution that works is to check the view controller's `transitionCoordinator`:

```
if self.transitionCoordinator?.presentationStyle == .popover {
    // Will actually be displayed within a popover
} else { // .formSheet (the default)
    // Will actually be displayed full screen
}
```

The above results hold true for at least iOS 15 - 17.

Note that `self.transitionCoordinator` and `self.parent?.transitionCoordinator` reference the same instance.

Answer (score -1):

Use "UIModalPresentationStyle" of the presentedViewController to detect presentation style is fullscreen or popover.

You can find more details here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle

Comment: I quickly added `print("ModalPresentationStyle: \(presentedViewController?.modalPresentationStyle)")` but it's in both cases `nil`

Comment: @Leo, Could you please share the code in GitHub so that we can take a look and solve this?

Comment: I tried this but found it to be `.popover` regardless

Answer (score -1):

Simply you can check this in the presented ViewController

```
if self.modalPresentationStyle == .popover {
     print("Popover presentation")
}
```

In case if the presented view controller is enclosed in a navigation controller, then use this

```
if self.navigationController?.modalPresentationStyle == .popover {
     print("Popover presentation")
}
```